# Genymotion 2.7 Emulator Refusing connection to ADB

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, genymotion

After upgrading to Genymotion 2.7 (released June 8th) Android Studio's integration with ADB is refusing connection with '192.168.56.101:5555'. When disabling the AS Integration with ADB I am able to `adb devices` and have it come up. However, once re-enabling it no devices are found.

This seems to be a bug in the new Genymotion Emulator(s).

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: It happened to me today also. I already sent an email to them reporting it. If i get a response i will let you know

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Genymotion 2.7.1 fixes the issue and was uploaded today:

> **Genymotion 2.7.1** (June 9th, 2016)
>
> Corrections
>
> This version fixes compatibility issues with Android Studio
>   (Genymotion virtual devices not being recognized by ADB)

[Reference](https://www.genymotion.com/release-notes/)

Answer (score 3):

Damien (Genymobile)
Jun 9, 10:13 CEST

Hi,

Thanks for your great interest in Genymotion!

We are currently investigating an ADB incompatibility issue between Genymotion 2.7.0 and Android studio.
Because this incompatibility issue may prevent you to develop using Genymotion, we stopped providing this new version and we recommend not using it.

You will find on our website Genymotion 2.6.0, which will work as before.
Virtual devices have been updated too, so downloading new virtual device should work fine.

A new version (probably 2.7.1) will be available soon.
This new version will fix this incompatibility issue.

We are very sorry for the inconvenience.

Best regards,

Damien
Genymotion Support Team

Answer (score 0):

To me, having the same problem, the most obvious problem is usually the right answer, something we do not consider until it stares us in the face.

1. Debugging options must be enabled and available on the Genymotion virtual device.
2. In the Debugging section, "USB debugging" must be on or enabled for ADB functionality to work.  If this is not the case, you will receive a connection that is refused.  If the Genymotion virtual device resets this item where "USB debugging" is not enabled, then you need to turn it back on the next time you start up the Genymotion virtual device.  Your device might not be saving state changes when you last performed a shutdown or power off action.
3. Sometimes, I have also found my Android Wi-Fi network not functioning as expected which is more of a reliability for tethering with mobile devices.  I tether my real mobile phone to my internet provider as the norm.  I am running two private networks as expected with use of Genymotion, first address range 192.168.43.X with "Bridged Adapter" mode, configured DHCP by my real mobile phone, Android 9, and/or my provider when tethering to the internet.  And, I am also using the "Host-only Adapter" as a network adapter with the address range of 192.168.151.X, configured using DHCP by VirtualBox. Make sure the "Host-only Adapter" adapter names are the same for the Genymotion device and the machine running Android Studio.
4. I find that I can make an ADB connection with either subnet.  However, if my real mobile phone has mobile data turned off, or if tethering is not enabled to create a Wi-Fi hotspot on my real mobile phone, then Genymotion will not have the Wi-Fi tethering TCP/IP address range available, '192.168.43.X' to connect to the internet.  This would leave only the Host-only Adapter subnet to communicate over while the internet is offline.
5. The standard USB fixed-wire TCP/IP address range is '192.168.42.x'; so if your real mobile phone is connected fixed-wire USB to your laptop or desktop tethering to the internet, you will likely use that address range instead.
6. Mobile Bluetooth wireless or fixed-wire USB tethering path IS NOT supported with Genymotion.

"Bluetooth is not supported with any of our Genymotion products for the moment, but we are aware that it is a popular feature and we are working hard to implement it in the future."
https://support.genymotion.com/hc/en-us/articles/360006511777-Does-Genymotion-support-Bluetooth-